# How to change URL of karaf features:install

Tags: java, maven, osgi, apache-karaf, fuseesb

```
JBossFuse:karaf@root> features:install wrapper
    Error executing command: URL [mvn:org.apache.camel.karaf/apache-camel/2.14-SNAPSHOT/xml/features] could not be resolved.
```

I get this message for features:install {ANYTHING}.

To be fair, I'm running jboss-fuse-full-6.1.0.redhat-379.zip on Windows.  So I should expect things to go wrong.  But for my edification, why is this happening?  Why is it going for the latest snapshot?

Answer (score 3):

If the bundle is not in the system directory and not in your local repository you should check `etc/org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.cfg` for the `org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.repositories` entry and make sure that the artifact can be resolved from there. You probably need to add the Apache snapshots repository [since the artifact is deployed there](http://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/org/apache/camel/karaf/apache-camel/2.14-SNAPSHOT/).